# How to write Xunit test case of factory design pattern code block which is tightly coupled?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, c#-4.0, solid-principles, xunit.net

I would like to write xunit test case of below method. Could you please suggest alternate design so i can write xunit test case with minimum change in my current project.

```
public ActionResult Index(int id = 0, AssetFilterType filter = AssetFilterType.All)
        {
            using (var tracer = new Tracer("AssetController", "Index"))
            {
                
                RemoveReturnUrl();
                ViewBag.JobId = id;
                var response = ContextFactory.Current.GetDomain<EmployeeDomain>().GetEmployeeFilterAsync(id, 
 CurrentUser.CompanyId, filter); // Not able write unit test case , please suggest alternate design. 
                return View("View", response);
            }
        }
```

**current design is as follow**

```
 public interface IDomain
            {
            }

 public interface IContext
        {
            D GetDomain<D>() where D : IDomain;
    
            string ConnectionString { get; }
        }

 public class ApplicationContext : IContext
    {
        public D GetDomain<D>() where D : IDomain
        {
            return (D)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(D));
        }

        public string ConnectionString
        {
            get
            {
                return "DatabaseConnection";
            }
        }
    }

 public class ContextFactory
        {
            private static IContext _context;
    
            public static IContext Current
            {
                get
                {
                    return _context;
                }
            }
    
            public static void Register(IContext context)
            {
                _context = context;
            }
        }
```

//var response = ContextFactory.Current.GetDomain**< EmployeeDomain>**().GetEmployeeFilterAsync(id,
CompanyId, filter);
This line serve purpose to call specific class method i.e GetEmployeeFilterAsync from EmployeeDomain. Although it is very handy and widely used in our                                application but due to design issue i am not able to write unit
test case.

Could you please suggest design so with the minimum change we can write unit test case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

step1  : Required library
[image]

step 2 : When the application starts , register required domain  like

protected void Application_Start()

UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();

Step 3:  create one static class and register all your domain

example

```
public static class UnityConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterComponents()
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();

           Initialize domain which will injected in controller 
            container.RegisterType<IPricingDomain, PricingDomain>();

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
        }
    }
```

step 4 :

so you can inject respective interface in  constructor
in controller file.

goal  : get rid of below any pattern in your project.
and start writing unit test cases.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the [Service Locator anti-pattern](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern), use Constructor Injection instead. I can't tell what `AssetDomain` is from the OP, but it seems as though it's the dependency that matters. Inject it into the class:

```
public class ProbablySomeController
{
    public ProbablySomeController(AssetDomain assetDomain)
    {
        AssetDomain = assetDomain;
    }

    public AssetDomain AssetDomain { get; }

    public ActionResult Index(int id = 0, AssetFilterType filter = AssetFilterType.All)
    {
        using (var tracer = new Tracer("AssetController", "Index"))
        {        
            RemoveReturnUrl();
            ViewBag.JobId = id;
            var response = AssetDomain.GetAssetFilterAsync(id, CurrentUser.CompanyId, filter);
            return View("View", response);
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming that `AssetDomain` is a polymorphic type, you can now write a test and inject a [Test Double](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Double.html):

```
[Fact]
public void MyTest()
{
    var testDouble = new AssetDomainTestDouble();
    var sut = new ProbablySomeController(testDouble);

    var actual = sut.Index(42, AssetFilterType.All);

    // Put assertions here
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mark for quick response , EmployeeDomain is just class which having many methods and inherited with IDomain interface. and we have multiple type of xxxDomain class files